# getting facebook friends list who have installed an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, friend

It's possible to know the facebook friends that they have installed a my fb app?
I have tried some ways directly using the online facebook developer tool but I have not been able to find a solution. I have tried both Graph API and FQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using FQL:

```
SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user
    WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) 
          AND is_app_user=1
```

Comment: You have any friend using the application? Because I use this query and it returns me the correct users. You can try setting `is_app_user = 0` to get the friends that are not using the app as well.

Comment: OK SORRY! You must have an active session to do this? I can do this by changing me () with a user id (no user logged)?